# NgOnInit not executing code inside Service subscripion

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

this is my `NgOnInit` method. Only "hello before" is executed in the console. I have tried doing `.subscribe( () => console.log("hello after"))`, but nothing is working inside this.

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("hello before")
    this.checkoutService.getTemplates().subscribe(({ templates }) => {
      console.log("hello after")
      this.templates = templates;
      console.log(templates)
    })
  }
```

CheckoutService:

```
     getTemplates(): Observable<{templates: Template[]}> {
        return this.http.get<{templates: Template[] }>("http://localhost:3000/checkout")
      }
```

/Checkout Endpoint Handler:

```
    router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
        var templates = [];
        var realTemps = [];
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ");
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token[1], 'secretkey');
        decodedFactoryId = decoded.factoryId
    
        Template.findAllByFactoryId(decodedFactoryId)
            .then((results) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    // THIS IS AN AVOIDABLE LOOP, quadratic time must be prevented by correctly formatting the data (TODO)
                    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        if (results[i][j].id) {
                            templates.push(results[i][j].id)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).then(() => {
                // Promise.all
                return Promise.all(templates.map(template => Template.findByTemplateId(template).then(result => {
                    console.log("here is the result: " + JSON.stringify(result[0]))
                    realTemps.push(result);
                })));
                
            })
            .then(() => {
                return realTemps;
            })
            
    })
```

There were 2 requests sent to http://localhost:3000/checkout. One of them responded with 200, the other didn't give back anything.

Here is my network tab:

[successful response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YTaP.png)

[no return?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPGT3.png)

How can I get the code inside my `checkoutservice` in the `NgOnInit` method to actually execute?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Browser Console to understand the problem better. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure the http call is executed correctly and returns a valid 2XX response?

Comment: I think that your service's handler does not executes properly - because of reasons. Check out your network tab to see if there is any response at first, then we will investigate further. :)

Comment: In order for `subscribe` to work, your `http` response has to be an `observable`. I do not see any observable returned in the code you have provided.

Comment: I added images to the post of the network tab. Thank you for your help. 
@Faisal I thought the return statement on the http method was an Observable? Where would I need to do this